# lidR version 4.0.3 lasmetrics disappear and make error

Tags: lidr

Before lidR v4.0.3 this code return datatable but now lasmetrics is replaced with different part function. How can i transform this code in lidR v 4.0.3 ?

```
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
ctg = readLAScatalog(LASfile)

myMetrics <- function(gps,int,rnu,nor,sdf,efl,sar,usd,psi,cla) 
{
  metrics <- list(
    min_gpstime <- min(gps),
    max_gpstime <- max(gps),
    min_intensity <- min(int),
    max_intensity <- max(int),
    min_returnnumber <- min(rnu),
    max_returnnumber <- max(rnu),
    min_numberofreturns <- min(nor),
    max_numberofreturns <- max(nor),
    min_ScanDirectionFlag <- min(sdf),
    max_ScanDirectionFlag <- max(sdf),
    min_EdgeOfFlightline <- min(efl),
    max_EdgeOfFlightline <- max(efl),
    min_ScanAngleRank <- min(sar),
    max_ScanAngleRank <- max(sar),
    min_UserData <- min(usd),
    max_UserData <- max(usd),
    min_PointSourceID <- min(psi),
    max_PointSourceID <- max(psi),
    min_classification <- min(cla),
    max_classification <- max(cla),
    tab <- table(rnu, nor),
    cla <- table(cla)
  )
  names(metrics) <- c("min_gps", "max_gps", "min_int", "max_int", "min_rnu", "max_rnu", "min_nor", "max_nor",
                      "min_sdf", "max_sdf", "min_efl", "max_efl", "min_sar", "max_sar", "min_usd", "max_usd",
                      "min_psi", "max_psi", "min_cla", "max_cla", "tab", "cla")
  return(metrics)
}

f <- function(cluster) {
  las <- readLAS(cluster)                          
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)              
  
  metrics <- lasmetrics(las, ~myMetrics(gpstime,Intensity,ReturnNumber,NumberOfReturns,ScanDirectionFlag,
                                        EdgeOfFlightline,ScanAngleRank,UserData,PointSourceID,Classification))
  return(metrics)                                  
}

opt_progress(ctg) <- FALSE
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 0
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 0
opt_output_files(ctg) <- ""
p_metrics <- catalog_apply(ctg, f)
metrics <- data.table::rbindlist(p_metrics %>% map(`[`, c(1:20)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lasmetrics` is deprecated since `v2.2.0` (Release date: 2020-01) and removed since `v3.0.0` (Release date: 2020-06). This means you did not update your packages for at least 2 years. `lidR` changed a lot during these two past years and I really suggested you to have an overview of the major changes in [v4](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/releases/tag/v4.0.0) and maybe the main changes in [v3](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/releases/tag/v3.0.0) as well.

You can use `cloud_metrics` as replacement it should work.

Comment: Thanks Jean Romain, but this create this error : Error in UseMethod("cloud_metrics", las) : 
  no applicable method for 'cloud_metrics' applied to an object of class "LAScatalog"

Comment: Ok I was wrong. Use your code and replace with `cloud_metrics`

Comment: in that case i have an error : Error: All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.

Comment: metrics `tab` and  `cla` are vectors and are invalid. This not related to `cloud_metrics` is was already invalid with `lasmetrics`

Comment: with lasmetrics it's ok because the script run with lidR v.2.2.0 ? in this case how can i have the table(rnu, nor) with new version ? Is it a good way ?

Comment: It means you found a bug and luckily it fitted your needs. `tab` and `cla` must be converted to `list` paying attention that it returns always the same number of data no matter the content `rnu`, `nor` and `cla`. If you need help you can open a new question.

Comment: ok i open a new.